# ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2

Tags: python, macos, pandas, matplotlib, backend

I'm trying to animate a scatterplot but get the following error. I had it working previously but its now returning this error on repeat.

```
ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2
```

I'll attach the animation code below. I had it working before so know it works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

XA = np.random.randint(80, size=(1000, 15))
YA = np.random.randint(80, size=(1000, 15)) 

XB = np.random.randint(80, size=(1000, 15))
YB = np.random.randint(80, size=(1000, 15)) 

XC = np.random.randint(80, size=(1000, 1))
YC = np.random.randint(80, size=(1000, 1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))
ax.axis('equal')

'''' Scatter Plot  '''

scatter_A = ax.scatter(XA[0], YA[0], c=['blue'], alpha = 0.7, s = 20, edgecolor = 'black', zorder = 2)
scatter_B = ax.scatter(XB[0], YB[0], c=['white'], alpha = 0.7, s = 20, edgecolor = 'black', zorder = 2)

offset = lambda p: transforms.ScaledTranslation(p/82.,0, plt.gcf().dpi_scale_trans)
trans = plt.gca().transData
scatter_C = ax.scatter(XC[0], YC[0], c=['red'], marker = 'o', alpha = 0.7, s = 10, edgecolor = 'black', zorder = 2,transform=trans+offset(+2))

'''Animate Function '''

def animate(i) :
    scatter_A.set_offsets([[[[[[[[[[[[[[[XA[0+i][0], YA[0+i][0]], [XA[0+i][1], YA[0+i][1]], [XA[0+i][2], YA[0+i][2]], [XA[0+i][3], YA[0+i][3]], [XA[0+i][4], YA[0+i][4]],[XA[0+i][5], YA[0+i][5]], [XA[0+i][6], YA[0+i][6]], [XA[0+i][7], YA[0+i][7]], [XA[0+i][8], YA[0+i][8]], [XA[0+i][9], YA[0+i][9]], [XA[0+i][10], YA[0+i][10]], [XA[0+i][11], YA[0+i][11]], [XA[0+i][12], YA[0+i][12]], [XA[0+i][13], YA[0+i][13]], [XA[0+i][14], YA[0+i][14]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]])
    scatter_B.set_offsets([[[[[[[[[[[[[[[XB[0+i][0], YB[0+i][0]], [XB[0+i][1], YB[0+i][1]], [XB[0+i][2], YB[0+i][2]], [XB[0+i][3], YB[0+i][3]], [XB[0+i][4], YB[0+i][4]],[XB[0+i][5], YB[0+i][5]], [XB[0+i][6], YB[0+i][6]], [XB[0+i][7], YB[0+i][7]], [XB[0+i][8], YB[0+i][8]], [XB[0+i][9], YB[0+i][9]], [XB[0+i][10], YB[0+i][10]], [XB[0+i][11], YB[0+i][11]], [XB[0+i][12], YB[0+i][12]], [XB[0+i][13], YB[0+i][13]], [XB[0+i][14], YB[0+i][14]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]])
    scatter_C.set_offsets([[XC[0+i][0], YC[0+i][0]]])


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,1000),
                              interval = 100, blit = False)


Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps = 10, bitrate = 8000)

ax.autoscale()

plt.draw()
```

I am running `Spyder 3.1.2` through `Anaconda 1.6.4`, `Python 3.5`, `Python 5.1.0`

Comment: Can you comment on what purpose the list-nesting (`[[[[[[[[[[[[[[`) serves here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message should give you all the hints you need. Removing the redundant brackets in your `set_offsets()` calls does the trick:

```
def animate(i) :
    scatter_A.set_offsets([[XA[0+i][0], YA[0+i][0]], [XA[0+i][1], YA[0+i][1]], [XA[0+i][2], YA[0+i][2]], [XA[0+i][3], YA[0+i][3]], [XA[0+i][4], YA[0+i][4]],[XA[0+i][5], YA[0+i][5]], [XA[0+i][6], YA[0+i][6]], [XA[0+i][7], YA[0+i][7]], [XA[0+i][8], YA[0+i][8]], [XA[0+i][9], YA[0+i][9]], [XA[0+i][10], YA[0+i][10]], [XA[0+i][11], YA[0+i][11]], [XA[0+i][12], YA[0+i][12]], [XA[0+i][13], YA[0+i][13]], [XA[0+i][14], YA[0+i][14]]])
    scatter_B.set_offsets([[XB[0+i][0], YB[0+i][0]], [XB[0+i][1], YB[0+i][1]], [XB[0+i][2], YB[0+i][2]], [XB[0+i][3], YB[0+i][3]], [XB[0+i][4], YB[0+i][4]],[XB[0+i][5], YB[0+i][5]], [XB[0+i][6], YB[0+i][6]], [XB[0+i][7], YB[0+i][7]], [XB[0+i][8], YB[0+i][8]], [XB[0+i][9], YB[0+i][9]], [XB[0+i][10], YB[0+i][10]], [XB[0+i][11], YB[0+i][11]], [XB[0+i][12], YB[0+i][12]], [XB[0+i][13], YB[0+i][13]], [XB[0+i][14], YB[0+i][14]]])
    scatter_C.set_offsets([[XC[0+i][0], YC[0+i][0]]])
```

I'm surprised that your code worked before. Note that I'm not running exactly the same setup, I'm on `macosx 10.13.5` with `Python 3.6` installed through `macports`.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that there might have been an `np.squeeze` in the `set_offsets` code in older/other versions that has been removed ...